# Удостоена орденов /орденами Как правильно?

Tags: управление

Единственная среди женщин удостоена полклвлдческих орденов/ полководческими орденами Суворова
(III степени) и Александра Невского

Comment: По существу, можно задать вопрос: удостоена (чего?) орденов. 



Answer (score 2):

"Орденов". Управление можно легко проверить в словаре, если вы не уверены, как используется глагол "удостоить".